# 3ds Max Animation in the Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

3ds Max gives you a variety of different ways to create animation, and a wealth of tools for managing and editing animation. I know this questions has been asked before but I'm curious if there's any update regarding whether it would be possible to display these animations in the Forge Viewer? I would be kind of similar to how you're currently managing the Fusion animations. This feature would add an amazing touch to the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Fusion animation is supported in Viewer, but unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no new update for the viewer to support 3ds Max animation.

Comment: hi @zhong-wu,
Do we have any updates for the viewer to support 3ds Max animation?

Comment: Sorry, but there is no update on that.